# How do I use openGL shader to reproduce this Photoshop implementation?

Tags: opengl, shaders, graphics-programming

Here are my Photoshop actions:

**step1 - convert the current image into gray**

[image: step1 - convert the current image into gray]

**step2 - use the default parameters, as showed in the screenshot**

[image: step2 - use the default parameters, as showed in the screenshot]

**step3 - use the 『Hue/Saturation』 to convert the grey image**

[image: step3 - use the 『Hue/Saturation』 to convert the grey image]

**step4 - use the parameters to complete**

[image: step4 - use the parameters to complete]

I did some search and find some code to make it available to convert to Grey as:

```
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;    
varying vec2 v_texCoord;    

void main()            
{
    vec4 c = v_fragmentColor * texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord);
    gl_FragColor.xyz = vec3(0.2126*c.r + 0.7152*c.g + 0.0722*c.b);
    gl_FragColor.w = c.w;

}
```

I would like to know whether the code is correct according to the parameters in Step 2 and what can I do with openGL shader to achieve step 3 & step 4.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably also include English description of what you want... I guess not many of us can read your screen shots.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234724/how-to-change-hue-of-a-texture-with-glsl/9234854#9234854) may help you with steps 3 and 4. It uses YIQ instead of HSV, but they're similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, step 1 and 2 are correct. [Here's proof](http://codepen.io/Paraknight/pen/LGYbXb?editors=100).

Step 3 and 4 can be done in a couple of ways. Following your steps to the letter, you can convert the RGB color to HSV, modify the values, and convert back to RGB. The first conversion is unnecessary though, since the image is grayscale, so we know the only thing that is affected is the "V" in HSV.

So you can use your image as V, and use those constant H and S values to get [something similar to what you want](http://codepen.io/Paraknight/pen/xZxRNE?editors=100). Subject to tweaking and experimentation of course.

Converting back and forth between RGB and HSV isn't the best idea for something like this though; perhaps in this case - if all you want is a slight blue/cyan tint - then you could instead just slightly tweak the blue and green channels and get the same result.